# How to run cucumber tags/step defs via command line?

Tags: jenkins, command-line, tags, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run specific scenario via the command line! With tags! How can I do it?

Comment: do you mean execute a single scenario via the command line? You cannot execute a step definition.

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added in build.gradle

plugin

```
id "se.thinkcode.cucumber-runner" version "0.0.8"
```

configurations

```
cucumberRuntime {
    extendsFrom testImplementation
}
```

task

```
cucumber {
    glue = 'classpath:com.ingenico.component.tests.cucumber'
    main = 'io.cucumber.core.cli.Main'  
    featurePath = 'src/test/resources/features'
}
```

Command

```
gradle cucumber --tags @tag
```

I get this code in https://github.com/tsundberg/gradle-cucumber-runner

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it with the help of tags. Define tag to that particular scenario and then can run.

EX:

```
gradle --daemon -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@testscenario1" build --info
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a single scenario from a feature by specifying the line number of the scenario in the feature file e.g.

`cucumber  path/to/feature/foo.feature#xx`

where xx is a line number which is in the scenario.

You can get help about running cucumber from the command prompt by running `cucumber --help`

If you are using java things are probably a bit different depending on how you run cucumber. Perhaps `mvn test -Dcucumber.options=”feature file path” + “line number of the scenario”` might work (got from googling  `run cucumber java from command line` and first result https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/run-cucumber-test-from-command-line-terminal/)

note: I do not use java so that part of my answer may not be much use